# mysql_close() alternative in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a rather long script, and I have noticed that I have too many dormant MySQL connections. I'd rather have them close before the script finishes running.

I was wondering what is the Doctrine way of closing connections? Something like mysql_close() in plain PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to your entity manager and then simply do this:

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

look in the documentation of doctrine about connections [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/connections.html)

Comment: That's the really old Doctrine 1 documentation

Comment: sry my fault ;) but he also doesn´t said which one he use^^ but yeah your answer is right

Comment: True, he should tag his question with Doctrine2 assuming that's what he is using. I guess I just assume everyone is on v2 since it's been out so long now.